# Placement of Twitter Meta Tag Failing Site Verification

Tags: twitter, meta-tags

So, I am throwing a hail Mary pass here, to see if anyone can catch it. I checked on [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/19057) and came up empty.

I added the following meta tag to the head of a website:

```
<meta property="twitter:account_id" content="3XXXXXXXX" />
```

I then confirmed that the tag is in the source HTML in between the head tags

Then from inside my account panel on Twitter there is a "Verify website" tool.
When I enter the URL and click "Verify website, I get the following:

```
Website ownership cannot be verified. Please add the metatag to your site.
```

Perhaps someone else has grappled with this and solved the issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I assume your websites is "https" to fix this you need to temporarily set your website not to display "http" in the address. Once you hit verify it should work and you can change it back to "https" when verified.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

So I tried the following, to no avail:

> Remove the middleware to redirect http:// URLs to https:// URLs (such that the site runs on HTTP without redirecting to HTTPS).

Unfortunately, this change did NOT seem to work by itself... so we clicked on the "Help?" button at the upper-right of the ads.twitter.com account dashboard.

After explaining the issue to the Twitter support staff, they were able to change something in their system (likely, invalidate some cached record somewhere) and the validation successfully went through.  So don't be afraid to reach out to Twitter for support!

After verification, we were able to re-introduce the HTTP -> HTTPS middleware on our site, while remaining verified with Twitter.